# Overwriting XmlSerializers standard DateTime serialization format with XmlAttributeOverrides

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Is it possible to change the serialization format of DateTime.

Basically i want this DateTime output in my xml file after serialization:

yyyyMMddHHmmss

... and a proper DateTime value after deserialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant.

However, If you control both the serializer and the deserializer, you can use the `[XmlIgnore]` attribute on the DateTime field, and create a custom property that formats (and parses) a string to the required format.